# How do you look for the index of a string in a large file and ask for a string at a certain index?

Tags: python, file

I am working on a program (Python) which needs to look through a large text file with a bunch of words in it.

The file is around 4.03 MB (over 4 million characters) of words seperated with a new line. ([This is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haeso.png))

What I want to do is look line by line in the file for a specific word then get the "index" of it. Also I want to be able to reach into the file and get a specific word by using the index without looking through the file.

How would I make this happen (preferably a very efficient code since my program will be looking through the file quite frequently)?

Comment: If you need efficient way then instead of storing it in .txt I think you should go for some efficient way of storage like database with indexing. Also you can try data structure like `tree`

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: 4 MB isn't really huge file, you can process it fast enough with simple loop. Get index: `ind = next(i for i, l in enumerate(file) if "word" in l)`

Answer (score 0):

By the index, do you mean to position of the word in the file? This will find the position of the specified text in a file...

```
file = open("text.txt","r")
text = file.read()
print(text.index("word"))
```

Comment: What I mean is to get the number of the line it's on and also to be able to access a certain line instantly without going through the whole file until I get to the line.